# How to start svg animation only when the div is in view port

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, svg-animate

I want to start an svg animation only when it is visible in the viewport. Because my svg container is at the bottom. I tried using some methods which can be seen below. Kindly sho me how to fix it.

```js
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
 var $elem = $(elem);
 // Get the scroll position of the page.
 var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
 var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
 var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

 // Get the position of the element on the page.
 var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
 var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

 return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}
function checkAnimation() {
 var $elem = $('#ourprocessFlowchartContainer');
 var animationTosquare =$("#contract_anim").get(0);
 console.log(isElementInViewport($elem));
 if (isElementInViewport($elem)==true) {
  // Start the animation
  animationTosquare.beginElement();
 } else{
  animationTosquare.endElement();
 }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(){
  checkAnimation();
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='ourprocessFlowchartContainer' class="ourprocessFlowchartContainer">
  <svg id="processFlowchart" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox = '0 0 740 300'>
 <!--  SVG content omitted -->
  </svg>
</div>
```

Please help me to get rid of this. This code will make my animation jerk as i visit my div container containing svg.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RandyRam/kpfgp8k7/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are re-triggering the animation every time checkAnimation() is called. I've added a flag to make sure this doesn't happen. Works here:

https://jsfiddle.net/FrancisMacDougall/bfngjsg0/

```
var waiting = true;
function checkAnimation() {
  var $elem = $('#ourprocessFlowchartContainer');
  var animationTosquare =$("#contract_anim").get(0);
  console.log(isElementInViewport($elem));
  if (isElementInViewport($elem)==true) {
    // Start the animation
    if(waiting) {
      animationTosquare.beginElement();
      waiting = false;
    }
  } else {
    if(!waiting) {
      animationTosquare.endElement();
      waiting = true;
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
checkAnimation();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkAnimation();
  });
});
```